# IPython Core Display Error HTML Object

Tags: html

I am getting above error after running my codes. Can anybody please explain why this error occurs. I just need to know for what reasons that happens. Thanks.

Comment: can you share your code here and give little more detailed of error

Comment: @shan-e-zehra, you should always ask questions in details. The question should be very well explained.

Comment: @elegant-user I need to know the possible reasons for mentioned error. <IPython.core.display.HTML object>